# Saving wide and deep tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm playing with [Wide and Deep learning example from Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py). I would like to save the trained classifier to be used for prediction tasks later on but I don't really see how. The `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` doesn't have a save method available and pickling the object fails as well.

Any ideas how to save it?

Answer (score 2):

The checkpoint saving section of [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints) should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring?

Specifically **Saving Variables** and **Restoring Variables**.  Additionally, you can use the **Checkpoint Files** to save the weights periodically (useful if your computer stops training halfway through, you don't have to start from the beginning).

Comment: This could be it but unfortunately Saver object requires access to Session which is afaik not exposed by the model.

Comment: Have you tried using the `model_dir` flag?   According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py the model_dir flag will give you: ```model_dir: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to continue training a previously saved model.```, so I bet that is used in the other classifiers you use in the deep and wide stuff.  If that's the case, then you can write your own .py file to restore it all and do what you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, setting model_dir works - the model is restored automatically the next time I instantiate the model. I was expecting I need to do something more than that. Thanks!